# Как обработать полученные данные от сервера JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#resultFromButton").one("click", function(){
$.ajax({
url: "some.php",
data-type: "html",
success: function(dataFromUrl){
$("#getSome").html(dataFromUrl); /// Хочется тут увидеть плавное
}                                /// появление данных от сервера(перед этим плавно скрыв то что было)
});                              /// Пробовал так:
});/// $("#getSome").fadeOut(1000).html(dataFromUrl).fadeIn(1000);
});/// Но там происходит чертовщина, видимо проблема в очередях, но понять не в состоянии
</script>
<p id="getSome">Answer here!</p>
<input id="resultFromButton" type="button" value="Get result!">
```

И да по поводу безопасности, не опасно ли явно указывать путь к php скрипту?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте

```js
var dataFromUrl = '123';     //возврат данных из ajax-запроса (для примера, вернулось '123'
setTimeout(function() { //здесь дается 1 секунда на отображение старого содержимого, в Вашем случае - не используйте, т.е. для исполнения берите все, что внутри данного блока
  var selector = $("#getSome"); //запоминается селектор (чтобы не обходить dom много раз
  selector.fadeOut(1000, function() { //использует затухание с временем анимации 1с, передает функцию обратного вызова, которую jQuery сам вызовет по завершению анимации
    selector.html(dataFromUrl).fadeIn(1000);//присваиваем содержимому тега содержимое переменной, инициируем появление со временем анимации в 1 секунду.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='getSome'>ololo</span>
```

Вас будет интересовать все, что внутри `setTimeout`.

По поводу безопасности - сам скрипт php надо писать так, чтобы не страшно было наружу вытащить. Потому как, если нужна подобная интерактивность - всегда можно вытащить, куда и какое шло обращение.

Comment: а почему как я пробовал не работает как надо? в чем проблема?

Comment: Потому что применяются одновременно 2 трансформации, 2я, не дожидается завершения первой.
Если бы подобные действия происходили синхронно с точки зрения js, на простейших анимациях браузер бы очень долго висел.

Comment: прокомментируйте свой код я не особо понимаю данной логики ибо все заврочивается в функцию задержку

Comment: функция задержки то и не нужна главное вложить в fadeOut fadeIn

Comment: да, об этом 2 раза написано=)

Comment: сплю маленько =)